# Traducción de "crowdfunding"

Tags: traducción, sustantivos, economía

El *crowdfunding* es cuando un proyecto, empresa o negocio obtiene fondos a base de pequeñas pero numerosas aportaciones de personas particulares.
Estas aportaciones pueden ser a cambio de algo (un producto futuro, algún tipo de privilegio) o a modo de donación.

¿Qué término en español sería el más adecuado para nombrar esta práctica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Financiación colectiva***, ***financiación en masa*** o ***financiación participativa***:

[Texto Colombiano](https://www.rutanmedellin.org//es/recursos/abc-de-la-innovacion/item/financiacion-colectiva-crowdfunding)

> Es un concepto que viene del término inglés crowdfunding, utilizado para  referirse a la cooperación que llevan a cabo varias personas para conseguir dinero u otros recursos que financien sus proyectos. Este es un método de financiación alternativo, en donde muchos aportantes apoyan con pequeñas contribuciones económicas, técnica similar a la que utilizan las ONG o las campañas de donaciones.
>
> La financiación en masa permite acceder a recursos económicos sin mediar con entidades bancarias, en donde los aportantes financian los proyectos a cambio de participar de los beneficios.

[financiacion participativa_texto español](https://www.emprendedores.es/gestion/a25568326/crowdfunding-financiacion-colectiva-alternativa-particulares-startup-pyme-plataformas/)

> De momento, y a fecha de hoy, en España operan, con la autorización previa de la Comisión Nacional de Mercado de Valores (CNMV), estas 26 plataformas de financiación participativa:

*Micromecenazgo* sería un error de traducción, a menos que el proyecto sea cultural. El *crowdfunding* nada tiene que ver necesariamente con proyectos pequeños ni con microfinanza en sí. Claro, existen iniciativas que tratan de los dos casos. Se utiliza el *crowdfunding* en proyectos de desarrollo económico por cuanto es fácil contactar con la gente en el internet. Muchas veces son pequeños pero no siempre.

En sí, el *crowdfunding* es levantamiento de fondos por internet abierto a todos.

Answer (score 5):

Etimológicamente, *crowdfunding* está formada por *crowd* y *funding*. *Crowd* se refiere a la multitud, a algo colectivo, mientras que *funding* es financiación. Por tanto, yo sugeriría:

## microfinanciación colectiva

Fundéu habló de ello en [*microfinanciación (colectiva)*, alternativa a *crowdfunding*](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/crowdfunding-mejor-financiacion-colectiva-financiacion-popularo-suscripcion-popular-982/):

> La expresión ***microfinanciación (colectiva)*** es una alternativa preferible al término inglés *crowdfunding*, que se emplea a menudo para referirse al mecanismo de financiación de proyectos por medio de pequeñas aportaciones económicas de una gran cantidad de personas.
>
> En la lengua general, el anglicismo *crowdfunding* puede sustituirse por la voz española *microfinanciación* (o *microfinanciación colectiva* si es necesario resaltar que son muchos los que contribuyen con estas pequeñas aportaciones).
>
> También pueden emplearse otras alternativas que se adapten mejor a cada caso concreto, como *financiación popular* o *micromecenazgo* (voz en general relacionada con actividades culturales, artísticas o científicas). El *crowdfunding* es un sistema que entronca asimismo con la tradicional suscripción popular.

Vemos pues que *microfinanciación* carece de la partícula que indique que es algo colectivo, de ahí que a mí me guste más algo tan explícito como *microfinanciación colectiva*.

Comment: Veo que no se menciona el más obvio "colecta".

Comment: Para mi, hay un problema con micro. A veces se levanta mucho dinero. microfinanción es poco dinero para pequeñas empresas.....además en inglés existe: microfinancing....crowdfunding puede resultar en millones....microfinancing is for low income or poor people to help them get out of poverty.

Comment: @Lambie lo de _micro_ es porque se compone de una suma de cantidades pequeñas. En un crowdfunding nunca he visto aportaciones especialmente grandes, de ahí que me parezca apropiado usar ese _micro_. Lo que mencionas de [_microfinanza_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfinanza) es algo completamente diferente, pues allí no hay una suma de aportaciones, sino una aportación pequeña y única.

Comment: @fedorqui Estás equivocado. crowdfunding solo se refiera al gran numero de personas que participa. ***Y no a la cantidad de dinero en si.*** Por eso micro no es correcto aqui. microfinanción y microfinanza comparten la misma idea semántica. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest_funded_crowdfunding_projects Lo he explicado en mi respuesta y lamento, pero no tengo ninguna duda con respecto al tema....

Comment: @Lambie creo que no me expliqué bien. A lo que me refiero es a que _micro_ denota la cantidad que aporta cada una de las personas. No hay ninguna _superaportación_, sino una serie de aportaciones pequeñas. La página que enlazas da la suma de las aportaciones, pero apostaría a que ninguna de ellas individualmente es grande.

Comment: @fedorqui Al contrario. Fue muy bien explicado y te equivocas. No hay ningún micro en el sentido.

Answer (score 4):

El término que suelo emplear, y que a su vez pienso que es el más utilizado, es **micromecenazgo**.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromecenazgo

> El **micromecenazgo**, *crowdfunding* o financiación colectiva, es un
>   mecanismo colaborativo de financiación de proyectos. El mismo
>   prescinde de la tradicional intermediación financiera, y consiste en
>   poner en contacto promotores de proyectos que demandan fondos mediante
>   la emisión de valores y participaciones sociales o mediante la
>   solicitud de préstamos, con inversores u ofertantes de fondos que
>   buscan en la inversión un rendimiento. En dicha actividad sobresalen
>   dos características, como son: la unión masiva de inversores que
>   financian con cantidades reducidas pequeños proyectos de alto
>   potencial y el carácter arriesgado de dicha inversión.

Comment: Esta respuesta ganaría bastante si copiases un poco del contenido relevante de esa página de wikipedia. Así, en lugar de tener que visitar el link, el contenido queda incluido en tu post con un par de párrafos relevantes a porqué "micromecenazgo" es una opción válida en español par "crowdfunding".

Comment: Me gusta la respuesta, si bien, como comenta la referencia en mi respuesta, el hecho de que se incluya _mecenazgo_ en el término hace pensar en temas culturales, cuando el _crowdfunding_ puede aplicar a cualquier sector. ([_mecenas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Oiue8xx): Persona que patrocina las letras o las artes_).

Comment: Creo que la mejor solución es: financiación colectiva. mecenazgo es para cultura.