# Traducción de "crowdlending"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, sustantivos, economía

Hace poco pregunté por la [Traducción de "crowdfunding"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/traducci%C3%B3n-de-crowdfunding). Esa pregunta la hice en parte para poder tomarla como referencia en esta que hago ahora.

El *crowdlending* es cuando un particular o empresa contrata un préstamo con una entidad financiera y ésta, a su vez, obtiene el capital a prestar a través de las aportaciones de múltiples inversores particulares.

- Por ejemplo: yo cojo un préstamo de 500€ al 10% con CofiBank, y CofiBank pone 100€ y le pide los otros 400€ a 40 personas que pone cada una 10€. Cuando yo devuelva los 550€, CofiBank obtendrá 110€ y los 40 inversores particulares obtendrán 11€ cada uno.

Como veis, se podría considerar un tipo de *crowdfunding*, pero tiene ciertas características concretas (aplica a préstamos exclusivamente, no hay altruismo ninguno, etc.) que hacen que no sean lo mismo o, al menos, se diferencien lo bastante como para que en inglés se usen dos términos distintos.

En la pregunta arriba enlazada, las respuestas ofrecidas fueron "microfinanciación colectiva", "financiación colectiva", "financiación en masa", "financiación participativa" y "micromecenazgo".
La respuesta aceptada fue "**financiación colectiva**".

Con eso en mente, **¿cómo traduciríais *crowdlending* de manera que refleje la diferencia con el *crowdfunding*?**

Comment: That looks like the English concept of peer-to-peer lending. Perhaps that might give people a clue.

Comment: Si _crowd-funding_ significa "la gente (crowd) me financia", _crowd-lending_ podría ser "la gente me da un **préstamo**", con la diferencia (sutil) de que en crowdlending esperan de vuelta dinero (y posible interés/beneficio, porque es un tipo de **inversión**), mientras que en el _crowdfunding_ se da el dinero a fondo perdido por altruismo o a cambio de otros servicios o "swag" (nunca dinero + intereses). Desconozco los entresijos, pero mi propuesta sería "micro(dependiendo de cómo hayamos valorado esto en la otra respuesta) **préstamo colectivo**"

Comment: Apoyo la propuesta de @Diego de nombrar al crowdlending  **préstamo colectivo** , (o  **préstamo comunal** como variante), implicando la fuente social-comunitaria del dinero.

Comment: Lo de crowd muchas veces implica que no hay un banco por medio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la respuesta aceptada para

> *crowdfunding* fue ***financiación colectiva***

en el caso de

> crowdlending se aplicaría mejor "***préstamo colectivo***".

Siendo que:

- *lending* es un ***préstamo***, y que
- para *crowd* se usó ***colectivo***

*Crowdfunding* y *Crowdlending* son simétricos en el fundamento de que los aportantes en ambos casos del dinero sea un grupo de personas, no necesariamente relacionadas.

Me parece además más pertinente esa definición que la de *colaborativo* (según el [enlace](https://comparatodo.es/noticias/diferencias-crowdlending-crowdfunding)  en la respuesta de @Lambie), porque el término colaborativo tiene un matiz o implicancia *de acción desinteresada o altruista*, que en este mecanismo no existe, ya que se cobra un interés pactado al inicio.

Comment: Por lo menos puse lo que se ve en sitios de finanzas. No dicen ellos colectivo en el caso éste. ¿Dónde están tus referencias?

Comment: Sólo respondí a la pregunta de una traducción que fuera adecuada al concepto. No se si haga falta la definición de colectivo (que RAE señala como agrupación o reunión de individuos en https://dle.rae.es/?id=9kxtVF3)

Comment: No estoy diciendo una referencia de la RAE o otro diccionario. Estoy hablando de lo que dicen los profesionales del asunto.

Answer (score 1):

Crowdlending

préstamos colaborativos

Como se explica en este sitio:

> Plataformas de crowdlending
>   Arboribus
>   Arboribus es una plataforma de crowdlending española muy conocida. Desde su fundación en 2009, ofrece **préstamos colaborativos** de 10.000 a 150.000 euros que pueden ser devueltos en un plazo de 60 meses.

[crowdlending- España](https://comparatodo.es/noticias/diferencias-crowdlending-crowdfunding)

Y aquí:

> **ECONOMÍA
>
>   El préstamo colaborativo, una opción en alza**

[préstamo colaborativo](https://www.estrelladigital.es/articulo/empresas/prestamo-personal-tendencia-alza-actualidad/20161019173919301083.html)

Aquí tenéis una explicación de la diferencia entre crowdfunding y crowdlending:

[crowdlending y crowdfunding + explicación técnica](https://www.crowdlending.es/blog/diferencias-entre-crowdfunding-y-crowdlending)

El término también se ve es site:.mx, site:.co y site:.ar.

En el caso de Argentina se ve también: finanzas colaborativas.

No averigüé otros países y formas de decirlo.

Comment: En Chile se usa el término como `cloudlending`: https://www.latercera.com/pulso/noticia/crowdlending-tipo-financiamiento-podria-preocupar-la-banca/239991/

Comment: Quise decir `crowdlending`, el autocorrector me jugó una mala pasada.

Comment: @saki Quiere decir los sites de tres países: México, Argentina y Colombia. ´¿No sabias que cada país tiene sus letras y que las busquedas por páis se hacen así? Hay muchos otros.//Y no entiendo porqué mi respuesta lleva dos votos negativos. Parece que los participantes no son traductores ...profisionales...

Comment: @saki Puse dos barritas // para señalar que no todo iba dirigido a ti sino a los algunos otros participantes. Para separar los comentarios. No comentaba sobre tu participación. Imagínate: ¿ decir algo contra la participación de algún indivíduo? Nunca lo haría//Aqui tienes una explicación técnica: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominio_de_nivel_superior_geográfico

Comment: @saki. My bien. No hay problema.

Answer (score 0):

Si quien otorga el préstamo es un banco cooperativo, tal vez estemos hablando de un "préstamo cooperativo", donde los aportes son realizados por los distintos socios.

Si se trata de un préstamo a gran escala, donde intervienen varias entidades financieras, estamos en presencia de un [préstamo sindicado](https://economipedia.com/definiciones/prestamo-sindicado.html).